# Will a DisplayPort 1.2 2k monitor work on 2560x1440 with MacBook Pro 2015?

Tags: mac, display, multiple-monitors, macbook, macbook-pro

I am planning to venture beyond the magical 1080p starting today and want to get a 2k monitor for my Macbook Pro 2015 13" retina.

I am planning on bying http://www.displaylag.com/benq-gw2765ht-review-1440p-ips-monitor/.

99% for programming.

Will this work fine with the Macbook? Will I get the 2560x1440 resolution, using DisplayPort to Thunderbolt or should I use a different cable?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, hardware shopping questions are off-topic here because they tend to go out of date quickly. You might try [hardwarerecs.se] after looking through their help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I use a dell U2715H with a DisplayPort to mini-DisplayPort with my late 2013 13 inch MacBook Pro.

It's not actually thunderbolt to display port. The Mini DisplayPort on your Mac happens to share the connector with the thunderbolt interface, no need to buy any adaptors just make sure you get the correct cable which will connect both ends.

Comment: @Foxhoudn,  Glad you got a  quick concise  answer, however please re review the site  Q&A terms and best practices regarding polling for  hardware selections and the like.  This site is for debugging hardware  /software NOT buying / compatibility advice which can often times be  found with simple web searching.

Answer (score 0):

this will work for sure! (sure=99,999%)

Comment: And I use DisplayPort 1.2 to Mini DisplayPort I assume?

Comment: Dp or Mini DP is just a form matter. Same capability. I am more worried about Dp to thunderbolt while I expected the reverse (output from thunderbold on the mac to displayport in on the monitor)

Comment: Thunderbold and DP are also compatible! So called Thunderbold <-> DP Adapters are plain cables with no active logic